# scaling a large image down in indesign, ant-aliasing issues?

Tags: adobe-indesign, resize, client-relations, dpi, digital-printing

I'm creating art for a zine run by fellow art students, they want an a3 image despite planning on planning to just scale that image down to a5 on InDesign to print as an a5 booklet. They have no requirements for dpi or colour profile but want a bigger image so it will be better quality.

I thought it was risky to scale an image down so much and that it could cause antialiasing issues?

It seems so unnecessary to me and I've already brought it up to them but they didn't seem to understand. I'm shooting photos which will look good from a5 or even a4 scale but there's no way I can make them look okay at a3 so I'm hoping you guys can word this stuff in a way that they will understand?

am I right that this is unnecessary or even a negative?

how would you word this/approach them?

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What are the dimensions of the original image in pixels?

Comment: I think you mean scaling an image up, rather than down. Your clients sound like they do not care too much about quality. Do you want to educate them, or are you worried for your reputation?

Comment: I guess i was partly stress ranting which is not what this forum is for so apologies. I was worried about both issues but in the end, I've just weaselled in some comments like' my art is converted to CMYK'  to try remind them that colour profiles exist etc. hopefully theyll ask a IT assistant to help.

Answer (score 2):

*How* images are to be used is really not your concern if you are merely taking photos. It sort of sounds as if you trying to train them in the use of InDesign as well. If hired as a *photographer*, that's really not your concern. If you *can't* shoot larger images, then tell them that, don't make excuses. Not everyone has a 10+MP camera. It's not unheard of to work within the constraints which are possible.

My preference.. shoot as large as humanly possible and then reduce for layouts.. so yeah.. A3 (or 8-10MP) images and then I'll set them up how I want them for an A4/A5 piece. It's not the photographer's concern if InDesign will [anti-alias] anything (I actually think you mean interpolate, not anti-alias).

Most knowledgable designers will reduce images with an image editor, such as Photoshop, then place the images into an InDesign layout. If they don't know enough to do this, then they certainly aren't going to be concerned with any interpolation which may occur due to drastic size reductions within InDesign.

Concerning A3 images.. the *viewing distance* for an image that large would typically mean you don't need a full A3 size image. An 8MP device will generally be fine. It's rare that an image meeds to fill an entire A3 page and if it does the viewing distance would mean it doesn't need to always be 300ppi. But yes, if you want full A3-size images you need at least 10MP, if not 16.

Comment: yeah, the issue is this isn't paid but their final product affects my grading on this project as it will count as my final piece so I keep trying to train them I guess. I ve accepted to just write off this project and leave it to them so I can focus on my own projects.